# How to transfer even numbers from vector a to vector b in ascending order?

Tags: c++

I've just started C++ and I'm in a tough spot, vectors. My problem is:
How do I put the even numbers from vector a into vector b in ascending order? 
For example: 7 4 2 9 5 -> 2 4
Also, if possible, I want the easiest algorithm to understand for now, nothing advanced. I only know bubble sort.

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: It might help to break your problem into 2 parts. First you want to be able to get all the even numbers from a vector and put them into a different vector. Then you want to sort the resulting vector in ascending order.

Comment: Use some [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Comment: I don't really do well with vectors, I lose myself in the for instructions as I don't really understand what each for does. Also I don't know how to construct a new vector and move the numbers there.

Comment: Start by [reviewing good documentation on how to use a `vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then write some simple programs to familiarize yourself with basic `vector` use. Once you are comfortable, write a program that only puts even numbers into a `vector`. Once you've written and tested that program so you know that it works, look into `std::sort`.

Comment: So write some pseudocode and post that. Do _something_, it doesn't matter if it doesn't work, at least you'll have a concrete question that isn't just "do this very simple thing for me"

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do that is just to copy all the even entries in the vector to another, then sort that vector. This would be pretty easy to implement, and if you already have a bubble sort algorithm that works well, you can just use that function instead of starting from scratch. To separate the even numbers into a new vector, you can do something like the following:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
{
    if(myVec[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        sortVec.push_back(myVec[i]);
    }
}
```

You can then do your bubble sort on `sortVec` after this, and you will have the even numbers in ascending order or descending order, and you can change it to do the same thing for odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a vector in ascending order:

```
#include <algorithm>
// intVec is your std::vector<int>
std::sort(intVec.begin(), intVec.end())
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
 - Filter your `vector` to a new one containing only even numbers, then `std::sort`
 - Write a function for sorting that sorts first into even and odd and then by size, and just use `std::sort` with that. Then, you will have a `vector` containing all numbers with even ones sorted in the beginning, and you can trim the vector if you like

The first one is a bit faster, but both have their charm , I think